# skip a line when it has a # character in python?

Tags: python

I would like some help about a problem that I'm facing as a new python programmer. I did a .txt file in c++ where there are some lines starting with # character which mean a comment and I want to skip those lines when I'm reading the file in my python script. How can I do that?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Which part of this task confuses you? Detecting whether a line starts with a `#` character? Skipping it once you've decided it should be skipped? Something else?

Comment: do you want specifically to "not read" the rest of the line, or do you want to just discard/ignore it?

Comment: `if not line.startswith("#"):`  work with the lines not starts with #

Comment: you'd better show your effort, for example your code

Comment: Wrote an answer but YES, this question is not a good format for the site, so removed it. We must not encourage help sucking (vampire).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you.

I'll read the whole file and save all lines into a list.

Then I'll iterate over this list looking for the first character in every line.

If the first char is equal to "#", go to the next line.

Otherwise, append this line to a new list called selected_lines.

My code isn't super effective, one-liner or etc... but I think this may help you.

```
lines = []
selected_lines = []    

filepath = "/usr//home/Desktop/myfile.txt"

with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    lines.append(f.readlines())

for line in lines:
    if line[0:1] == "#":
        continue
    else:
        selected_lines.append(line)
```

Comment: This is easier by iterating over `(line for line in open('myfile.txt') if line[:1] != '#')`. Your code reduced to one line

Comment: replace external parens with square braces to have the list

Comment: i'm not that good yet with one liners heheh.... but thanks for your hint! what do you mean by "replace external parens with square braces"?

Comment: WARNING: it is not `next` the word you need. it is `pass` or `continue`. However, `next` will not explode being a line, since it just evaluates an expression returning such built in function (that expression is just a value with no use)

Comment: replace external parens with sqbraces is: `[line for line in open('myfile.txt') if line[:1] != '#']`. This is called list comprehension. The first stuff i tol you was called generator comprehension.

Comment: I think using `line.startswith('#')` would be more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work if it's just the beginning character.  If you need it to ignore comments after code, you would need to modify it to `if '#' in line:` and handle it accordingly.

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Use continue so your code doesn't become a nested mess.
        # if this check passes, we can assume line is not a comment.
        if line[0] == '#':
            continue
        # Do stuff with line after checking for the comment.
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I just put the if and I solved.